# Issues With Shadows

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, lighting, shadows

I'm making a character, but every time I put it in render mode no shadows pop up. I feel like this has a simple solution but I can't figure it out. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file or at least show a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really be specific without your .blend file or screenshots, but here's something that might have caused the problem:[image]
You might have switched off shadows in object properties > viewport display or if you're using cycles (not applicable to eevee):[image] You might have switched off shadows here.